# Incompatibility between krb's AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96 and Microsoft Windows Domain

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, kerberos

I am trying to upgrade our system's kerberos encryption from RC4 to AES256. I've set up a Microsoft Windows Domain user with AES256 encryption support.
I'm creating a keytab for kinit using ktutil on Linux:

```
ADD_ENTRY="addent -password -p $DOMAIN_LOCAL_USER@$DOMAIN_UPCASE -k 2 -e AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96\n$DOMAIN_LOCAL_PASS\n"
echo -e "$ADD_BASE_ENTRY\n$ADD_ENTRY\nwkt user.keytab\nquit\n" | ktutil
```

kinit works well with that keytab.

However, when I'm creating an SPN for this user using ktutil on Linux

```
ADD_BASE_ENTRY="addent -password -p MSSQLSvc/$SHORT_HOSTNAME.$DOMAIN_LOWCASE@$DOMAIN_UPCASE -k 2 -e RC4-HMAC\n$DOMAIN_PASSWORD\n"
echo -e "rkt spns.keytab\n$ADD_BASE_ENTRY\n$ADD_ENTRY\nwkt spns.keytab\nquit\n" | ktutil > /dev/null 2>&1
```

then I'm unable to accept incoming connections:

```
GSS-API major_status:000d0000, minor_status:000186a6
GetGSSError(): GSS Error ERR_MAX: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
GetGSSError(): GSS Error ERR_MIN: Request ticket server MSSQLSvc/greensqlcent21.kerberosdc.msft:1434@KERBEROSDC.MSFT kvno 2 enctype aes256-cts found in keytab but cannot decrypt ticket
```

This has worked well when I was using RC4_HMAC for everything.

**Edit:**

My application mimics an MSSQL server. I'm running as a User (not as the computer) and I have set this user to login with AES256. Initially, I have kept the SPNs in the incoming keytab file with RC4_HMAC (this used to work when the domain user was also authenticating using RC4_HMAC), but I got an error that the gssapi accept function is looking for an AES256 entry in the SPN keytab file. So I changed the SPN keytab file to also use AES256 and got the above error.

**Edit 2:**

Tested with both Windows 2k8 and 2k12 as Domain Controllers. Both fail.

Comment: I've always created keytabs using the MS Windows Server command 'ktpass". You have to run it on a Windows server for it to work. Any way you can use ktpass instead?  What version of Active Directory is running?

Comment: I thought I saw a syntax error in ktutil, but since kinit works well for that keytab I'll rule that out.  The pertinent error here is *kvno 2 enctype aes256-cts found in keytab but cannot decrypt ticket*.  Can you explain more of what you're trying to do here.  Are you trying to authenticate to a SQL service on a Windows machine in the domain from a Linux box using the keytab?  I say that because this looks like the target service the process is trying to authenticate to:  MSSQLSvc/greensqlcent21.kerberosdc.msft:1434

Comment: My application mimics an MSSQL server. I'm running as a User (not as a the computer) and I have set this user to login with AES256. Initially, I have kept the SPNs in the incoming keytab file with RC4_HMAC (this used to work when the domain user was also authenticating using RC4_HMAC), but I got an error that the gssapi accept function is looking for an AES256 entry in the SPN keytab file. So I changed the SPN keytab file to also use AES256 and got the above error.

Comment: Also, I cannot use ktpass, because my application is creating these SPN on-the-fly and has to run on Linux (I have already automated joining the domain using krb5, ldap and samba)

Comment: Is your application server which is mimicking SQL Server a J2EE Server?

Comment: @Shloim - curious, what kind of application mimics an MSSQL server?  Is it a commercial off-the-shelf one, or an in-house built one?

Comment: Still haven't heard the version of AD involved here.  It's pertinent.

Comment: The application is a database proxy (so I'm accepting Kerberos tokens and creating a delegated token for the actual server, but right now I am failing at the accept phase). It is a C/C++ server using BSD sockets. I'm failing with both Windows Server 2k8 and 2k12.

Comment: If Kerberos delegation is working with encryption type at RC4-HMAC, then I would say that your C/C++ server is not currently supporting AES256-SHA1.  Maybe there is an updated module for it which you need to search for.

Comment: After conferring with the krb-dev mailing list, it would seem that ktutil for linux is using a different salt for AES256 than MS Active Directory. Since RC4 does not require a salt, it works well. I would have to rewrite ktutil's code to use the same salt as Microsoft in order to fix this.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the krb-dev mailing list?

Comment: http://mailman.mit.edu/pipermail/krbdev/2017-October/012848.html

Comment: Have you fixed this?

Comment: Not yet. Put it aside for a while.

Comment: Did you fix it? I got a similar one as `kvno 3 enctype aes256-cts found in keytab but cannot decrypt ticket`

Comment: Nope, sorry. We stayed with RC4 for now.